# I can't install Ubuntu because of a problem related to partition alignment

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive

The hard disk of my computer failed, so I bought a new external hard disk, to install Ubuntu on it, and let me use my computer.

I have experience installing Ubuntu in an USB flash memory,

So I followed those steps and everything was going fine until in the window of partition menu I pressed the "Install Now" button.

Data: My new HDD is of one tera, "Adata" is the brand and it is connected by an USB cable.

It appeared the following warning:

> The partition /dev/adb5 assigned to / starts at an offset of 2048 bytes from the minimum alignment for this disk, which may lead to very poor performance. Since you are formatting this partition, you should correct this problem now by realign the partition, as it will be difficult to change later, to do this go back to the main partition menu, delete the partition, and recreate it in the same position with the same settings. This will cause the partition to start at a point best suited for this disk.

There were also three buttons: "x", "cancel" and "accept". Whichever I click on it returns me to the partition menu.

I do as the message says: I erase all the partitions and I created a new one using it as / but that doesn't solve the problem, and the warning appears again, I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Using the program gparted is not helping nor working at all.

I would like to install it although it would have a low performance, but it doesn't let me.

I've been also creating two or more partitions, for example I created one of the size of half of the disk and the second of the rest of the size, this changes the offset bytes number that appears in the warning, but that does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how the problem was solved:

- I first created a partition of 100 MB and the rest of the space... I used it as / (root) and later it appeared the same warning.
- Then I created an additional partition of 50 MB and I did the next same step said above, but I noted that the offset bytes number in the warning message were decreasing in MB. Then I likewise were decreasing the MB number of the future additional partitions in half.
- So at the end, when I finally created the last additional partition of 25 MB... Success... It finally let me install Ubuntu on my new HDD.

So I ended up having 4 partitions in total.

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted if the problem is solved

Comment: OK, but this say that I have to wait two days to do that.